# Check if one environments has requirements

Tags: pip, conda

I have multiple conda environments for different projects and am now looking into using some code that has a `requirements.txt` file.

Since there are only a few requirements I was wondering if there was a way to check if one of my already existing conda envs has the required packages instead of creating yet another env just for this task.

Many thanks

Comment: Is this `requirements.txt` of Conda packages or PyPI packages? They're different and thus have different answers.

Comment: It is for PyPI packages, thanks for pointing this out!